# How can I find the pitch-accent pattern for 頭高型?

Tags: phonology, pitch-accent, phonetics

I don't mean the meaning of 頭高型, but the pitch-accent pattern of the actual word 「頭高型」. I've found several pitch-accent dictionaries including the two OJAD sites ([here](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/eng/pages/home) and [here](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/eng/phrasing/index)), but the first site doesn't give the pitch classification (like 0 if it was 平板), and the second doesn't have an entry for it.

This seems like a word that should be in pitch-accent dictionaries, given it's a pretty common word for talking about pitch-accent.

Does anyone know any better resources, and/or the pitch-accent pattern for 頭高型?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

頭高型 is a technical term which is also a compound noun. Ordinary native Japanese speakers usually have no idea about what 頭高型 means, so it's not surprising to me if it is not listed in an accent dictionary.

Anyway, according to online videos ([1](https://youtu.be/7V9Pn54FT6w?t=95), [2](https://youtu.be/FGty16e4JMM?t=73)), the pitch accent of 頭高型 is あたまだかがた【LHHHHHH】. I think you can infer this if you know the pitch accent of 頭 and ～型.

Related:

- [What are the pitch-accent rules for compound nouns?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29488/5010)

Comment: This is also how I hear the word (LHH HH HH). As a compound with kunyomi reading, It follows the pitch pattern of the kunyomi parts closely.

Comment: I think you only need to know the accent of 〜型, since it makes everything flat, right? けつえき{LHLL}→けつえきがた{LHHHHH}

Comment: @DariusJahandarie TBH I have never thought of this rule, but looks like you're correct. 型 is enough...