# Standard Japanese Youtube phrases for ending a video

Tags: english-to-japanese

I've been searching various Japanese Youtube videos trying to find the equivalent of "Remember to like/comment/subscribe, and hit the notification bell".

So far the closest thing I've found is

> チャンネル登録お願いします

but is there a standard phrase that includes 'liking' 'commenting' or 'hitting the notification bell'

Comment: I don't know why Youtubers do this.  It's not like people are like, "I enjoyed this video and I'd like to let the creator know.  I just don't know how to do that," or, "I wish there was an easy way for me to automatically be told about all their new videos as they come out."  It sounds so desperate, not to mention redundant.  If you have good content, people will naturally do it.

Comment: @istrasci a good salesman can sell a bad product, but a bad salesman can't sell a good product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liking is いいね or 高評価, and commenting is コメント, so you could say:

> 高評価、コメント、チャンネル登録お願いします。

But this is not a standardized set phrase, and everyone uses different phrases.

I personally haven't seen anyone mentioning a notification bell at the end of a video, but you could say 通知ONをお願いします, 通知設定をお願いします, etc.

Comment: It sounds like to me that チャンネル登録 is ちゃんえるとうろく{HHHHHHLLL}, is this correct with how you say it?

Comment: @firuvi In standard Japanese, there is always a shift in pitch between the first and the second sound. It's ちゃんねるとうろく【LLHHHHLLL】. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29488/5010), too.