# Pitch accent of 第+counter

Tags: pitch-accent, numbers

What are the pitch patterns for 第+number/counter combinations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- When `第 + N` is followed by nothing or is pronounced on its own:

  - When N ≤ 10, pronounced as heiban:

    > - だいよん【LHHH】
    > - だいろく【LHHH】
    > - ラジオたいそう【LHHHLLL】 だいいち【LHHH】 ([ラジオ体操](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_calisthenics)第1)
    > - こうきょうきょく【LHHHLLLL】 だいご【LHH】 (交響曲第5; Symphony No. 5)
  - When N ≥ 11, 第 is pronounced as atamadaka, and the number is pronounced as usual (the same way as when 第 is absent):

    > - だいじゅうさん【HLLLHHH】
    > - だいにじゅうよん【HLHLLLHL】
- `第 + N + counter` (counter is 回, 章, 話, 日, 条, 項, etc):

  - 第 is pronounced as atamadaka, and the `N + counter` combination is pronounced as usual:

    > - だいごかい【HLLHL】
    > - だいにじゅうごわ【HLHLLLHL】
- `第 + N + の/に` as a no-adjective meaning "N-th" or `第 + N + は` meaning "N-th point is...":

  - (N ≤ 10) Everything is pronounced as atamadaka.

    > - だいいちに【HLLLL】 (第一に; First of all...)
    > - だいにには【HLLLL】, だいには【HLLL】 (第二(に)は; Second of all...)
    > - だいいちのもんだい【HLLLLLHHH】 (第一の問題; the most important problem)
    > - だいにのてき【HLLLLH】 (第二の敵; second enemy)
    > - だいさんのビール【HLLLLHLL】 ([第3のビール](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E3%81%AE%E3%83%93%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB))
- `第 + N + noun` (noun is a non-counter noun, usually with ≥ 2 kanji):

  - When N ≤ 10, everything is [pronounced like a long compound noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29588/5010):

    > - だいなながくしょう【LHHHHLLLL】 (第7楽章; 7th Movement)
    > - だいろくかんたい【LHHHHLLL】 (第6艦隊; 6th Fleet)
    > - だいさんいいんかい【LHHHHHLLL】 (第3委員会; Third Committee)
  - When N ≥ 11, だい is pronounced as atamadaka. The number and the noun is connected like a long compound noun ([◯◯]{HH}), but the number part has its own accent:

    > - だいにじゅうさんけんきゅうしつ【HLHLLLLHHHHHLLL】 (第23研究室; Research Room 23)
    > - だいななせんろっぴゃくごじゅうよんくかく【HLLHHLLLHHHLHHHLHHLL】 (第7654区画; District 7654; Note that the よん part is heiban)

Comment: For <10, I feel like だ＼い・N is also quite common, or in fact more common especially when it’s 第Nの. On the other hand 第N when used as a noun (eg to refer to 第N艦隊 or similar) is more commonly heiban… 

Comment: @DariusJahandarie 第Nに/の is indeed atamadaka, so I incorporated that, but I doubt だ＼い is common outside those.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if it’s just me but I could imagine atamadaka occurring as say 第四は too if you are looking at a list with someone (and abbreviating the counter), where it’s behaving purely as an ordinal (which seems to basically be atamadaka) as opposed to the actual name of something (which is where it seems to consistently become heiban)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Yes 第4は meaning "the fourth point is" is indeed atamadaka (thank you for reminding me of this), but I'm not sure "purely as an ordinal" is the correct way to describe this. For now, I feel the atamadaka reading is limited to only a few patterns...