# Why isn't there の in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives

> 素晴らしい迷路庭園デス。

Isn't 迷路 a "no-adjective"? I would have expected the sentence to be: 素晴らしい迷路の庭園です。Are they both correct or is my version incorrect?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010 Well, 迷路庭園 is not an established 熟語 at least to me, and I'll probably use 迷路の庭園 to describe [this](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2141468690762125501). But those who like gardens or mazes may use this as an established concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of thinking is actually quite valid.

In this particular case, however, 「迷路庭園{めいろていえん}」 should be regarded as one word meaning a "***labyrinth***" or "***maze garden***".

「迷路**の**庭園」, therefore, would sound slightly wordy though it would be understood by every Japanese-speaker.  It just sounds a little too "explanatory".

Comment: Thank you! What about な adjectives? Is it the same? For instance: "あなたとの数々の知的冒険は楽しかったですよ。"

Comment: Unless you have an "established" compound word, it would usually be more natural to use a 「な」.  「知的な冒険」, therefore,  would sound better than 「知的冒険」 in more cases, but  if the latter were used  as a **key word** and used repeatedly in a certain context, then it would be more natural **not to** use the 「な」.  Japanese is highly contextual like that.