# Why is 英語教師 possible but 英語先生 not possible?

Tags: particles, particle-の

Why is it ok to say both 英語教師 and 英語の教師 but not 英語先生, just 英語の先生?

Comment: See this question for relevant information. In particular, @naruto's answer relates to your question. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/the-omission-of-an-implied-%E3%81%AE-creates-the-appearance-of-a-%E5%9B%9B%E5%AD%97%E7%86%9F%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%88%E3%81%98%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%8F%E3%81%94/19379#19379

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interesting question. It's actually a peculiar feature of the word 先生.

It may sound confusing, but [先生](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/126630/meaning/m0u/) does *not* literally mean "teacher" even though it is the most basic word for it today. It is an honorific title addressing a learned person, like "sir", "master", "honorable" etc.

> **２** 教師・師匠・医師・代議士など学識のある人や指導的立場にある人を敬っていう語。呼びかけるときなどに代名詞的に、また人名に付けて敬称としても用いる。「先生がたにお集まりいただく」「先生、お元気ですか」「鈴木先生」

For this reason, 先生 can only stand for "teacher" when it is used alone, and if attached to other nouns, it becomes a form of address.

> 英語教師 *English teacher*
>   英語先生 *Mr./Ms. English*