# Would you say 日系アメリカ人の歴史のポータル or 日系アメリカ人の歴史ポータル?

Tags: words

Which is correct? My gut tells me it's the second one, but I've asked and someone told me the first is probably the one to use. Reasons being ポータル is not a common katakana word.

Comment: That's quite opinion-based, but I'll second you (pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

Neither is incorrect, but I would say 日系アメリカ人の歴史についてのポータル(サイト) if there is enough space. (This ポータル means a web portal, right?)

The first one has two simple の's in succession, which is not bad but may be seen as unsophisticated. (Three or more の's is [seen as clumsy by many](https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/article/COLUMN/20100430/347675/).) The second one treats 歴史ポータル [like an established set phrase](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19379/5010), but I don't think it is a well-known established concept. Although these are minor problems, it's better to avoid them when possible.

Comment: Yes ポータル refers to webpage portals; as in a wiki portal for chemistry

Comment: @naruto can the first sentence be expressing more about the Portal (as Portal would constitute as a main noun), like; as in here is the portal which is about history (main noun modifier) and that too of Japanese American (Modifier's Modifier) (Like, in a website where there are 30-40 different decent portal and that too about different aspects like history, culture etc.). Whereas, the 2nd one expresses about here is the History Portal that is about Japanese American, as here the modified noun would be History Portal that talks about Japanese?