# Use of ママ as suffix to a name?

Tags: translation, names, suffixes

I've seen ママ used as as sort suffix to names before.

Like here: https://more.hpplus.jp/odekake/o-news/43298/1/

> 彼ママと初対面

What I'm asking here is: Can I add ママ after any name and that will mean I'm referring to their mom?

E.G. とも君ママ is Tomo-kun's mom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I add ママ after any name and that will mean I'm referring to their mom?

Generally speaking, no. But [people often drop の between nouns](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010) when it's an important and/or recurring concept to them. For example, when two people are casually talking about 木村さんのママ, they may start contracting it to 木村ママ during the conversation. In your case, 彼ママ is not a common phrase (I think I saw it for the first time today), but it's straightforwardly made from 彼(氏)のママ, and it's not difficult to grasp the intended meaning with the aid of the context.

By the way, ママ is occassionally used as a suffix for a real mother or someone with a mother-like character. For example [尾木直樹](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%BE%E6%9C%A8%E7%9B%B4%E6%A8%B9)'s nickname is 尾木ママ because of his character and feminine way of speaking. It's more like "Mother Ogi" rather than "Ogi's Mom".

Comment: is it safe to say that its a slang ?

Comment: @アニケン＿スカイワカー Do you mean 彼ママ? It's definitely informal, but I'm not sure if it's "safely a slang"...

Comment: may be it is slang in making....who knows after some years someone will answer this comment with Yes.

Comment: @アニケン＿スカイワカー 彼ママ is a rather straightforward combination of 彼 and ママ, both of which are relatively informal but not particularly slangy.