# What does 筋肉要塞（キンニクヨウサイ）mean?

Tags: grammar, words

> 歩く筋肉要塞か　てめえは！

From what I know, this translates to "Are you a walking 筋肉要塞?" or more literally "As for you, a 筋肉要塞 that walks?"

But what does the **筋肉要塞** mean? All I can get is "*fortress of muscle*". Is this some Japanese equivalent for "*meathead*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

筋肉要塞 is not a set phrase or anything. It's just a one-off joke meaning "muscle fortress" or "fortress of muscle". There is nothing more than the literal meaning. (By the way, 脳筋 is a common slang term that is very close to "meathead".)

If you know [this "rule"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19365/5010) and felt that 筋肉要塞 was likely to be an established set phrase, your intuition is basically correct, but a *yoji-jukugo* sounds a little nicer as a (temporary) catchphrase. Besides, since there's another modifier (歩く), saying 歩く筋肉**の**要塞 would make the entire phrase slightly lengthy, so the の was omitted.

Comment: thanks. This really helped