# How would one say "red snow" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

This is a simple question, but Google translate hasn't exactly provided an adequate answer.
How would one translate "crimson snow" or "red snow" to Japanese? And what would the transliteration be?

Alternatively, how about "bloody snow" (further "snow soaked in blood") or something along those lines?

The only answers I've found so far are せきせつ (sekisetsu) and あかゆき (akayuki) but I do not know if those are any good!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A simple and unsurprising translation should be 赤い雪 (*akai yuki*, "red snow"). If you want something more nuanced, "crimson snow" is 深紅の雪 (*shinku no yuki*) and "blood-soaked snow" is 血に染まった雪 (*chi ni somatta yuki*).

By せきせつ/あかゆき, did you mean 赤雪? How did you come up with this? It's not a word recognized by an average Japanese speaker, and [you cannot coin a new word by combining arbitrary two kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17996/5010). せきせつ is usually interpreted as 積雪 which means "accumulation of snow on the ground". On the other hand, 白雪 (しらゆき) exists as a word, and you can safely use it to refer to "white snow".

Comment: I found the translations through Google, which is why I said that I am not sure they even make sense (I am in no way an experienced Japanese learner, so I apologise for silly mistakes).

Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%B5%A4%E9%9B%AA) knows 赤雪, but it seems to be a geological term.