# Parsing of word components/construction in Japanese

Tags: etymology

Is 所為's components supposed to make it parsed as "thing that is wrought from a place"? Is 勉強 similar to 所為 in that way with the parsing of its components? What are the (all the) other ways (that you can find/think of) of parsing the components or understanding the construction of 漢語?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can kanji compounds be formed arbitrarily?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17996/can-kanji-compounds-be-formed-arbitrarily) It's basically not a good idea to worry about the components of a word too much. There are many obscure compounds, and 所為 is one of them.

Comment: Knowing the etymology of 所為 requires knowledge of (Classical) Chinese syntax. As such I think the first part of this question is a valid question on this site, even if the answer is "the etymology relates to Classical Chinese". The last part is a bit too open-ended for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding 勉強 and 所為 in particular, no, they have different structures.

There should be several ways to categorize structures of kango, but looking at [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%86%9F%E8%AA%9E_(%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97)#%E7%86%9F%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E6%A7%8B%E9%80%A0%E3%81%A8%E5%88%86%E9%A1%9E), 勉強 can be categorized as 並列構造 (with 類義語) since 勉 and 強 both mean some sort of enforcing (not necessarily negatively though).

On the other hand, 所為 is the same thing as:

> 「所得（しょとく、suǒdé）」は「得（う）る所（ところ）」と訓読する。特殊な補足構造の一種、あるいは認定構造の一種と解釈される。

In case of 所為{しょい}, it is 為{な}す所{ところ} where 所 means essentially *that which*. So [所為](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%89%80%E7%82%BA_%28%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%84%29/) is *that which (subj.) does* = behavior, cause (as someone who 'started').

所得 is *that which (subj.) gets* = income, and similarly for

- 所見 *that which (subj.) sees* = observation
- 所業 *that which (subj.) did* = somebody's (usually wrong) doing

Comment: Why does 所 come first in all of those words

Comment: @StarPeep That's the grammar of classical Chinese. (In my understanding,) It is similar to *that which* in terms both of grammar and of meaning. It encapsulates what follows and means *the thing that ...*