Etymology of 能力
What is the rough etymology of 能力 (ability, capacity)? Or how do 能 (ability / talent) and 力 (power / strength) come together to form the meaning of ability / capacity? Specifically, how does 力 (power / strength) contribute to the meaning of ability / capacity?

Does it help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17996/7810

Just a guess: To me, “to have the power to do X” and “to be able to do X” are pretty similar in meaning in English, at least superficially. So, it doesn’t surprise me that “power” and “ability” are connected in Japanese as well.

In my experience as an amateur learner, there isn’t always an exact correspondence between the meanings of individual kanji and the meaning of the overall word when it comes to Sino-Japanese vocabulary. After all, we're talking about words borrowed from Chinese many hundreds of years ago, so there’s plenty of time for “semantic drift” to happen. Still, IMO the meanings are usually relatively straightforward—you just might have to think about it for a bit (or use your imagination) before it clicks.

@JoshGrosso It usually still helps me understand / remember the word if I can at least see a way that the meaning evolved over time (even if its only a theory).

@broccoliforest I'm not sure which of the listed relationships it is though, but an interesting read nonetheless.

@Pheonix If you ask me, I'd say this is a synonymous compound. 能 has a sense "able" and 力 has a sense "able" too.

力 indeed contributes very little to the meaning of 能力, but it's important because 能 is probably too short as a word. We also have 脳【のう】 (brain), 農【のう】 (agriculture), 嚢【のう】 (cyst), and so on.
In compounds with more complex meanings, 能 is used without 力, for example 無能, 権能, 異能 and 全能. In certain fixed phrases like 能ある鷹は爪を隠す, 能 is used as an independent word, but this is considered exceptional.
Many Japanese compounds are like this, and similar questions have been asked several times:

If 校 is the kanji for school, why do I need 学 to actually say school?
Contribution of 気 to the meaning, for example, 勇気 and 勇
What's the difference between 重責 and 責任?


I'm assuming there should still be some reason (no matter how seemingly random or unintelligible for the modern mind) why that specific supporting kanji was used, right?

@Phoenix Wiktionary claims that it came from the Chinese word 能力, which also has the meaning of “ability”. So I suspect the answer might boil down to the original Chinese etymology.

@Pheonix What do you mean? 力 is not random or unintelligible at all to me in this context. Maybe you're making a wrong assumption that 力 is only for physical strength? We commonly say 理解力, 記憶力, 計算力 and so on, which are all part of 能力. 女子力 is also unrelated to physical strength.

@naruto I thought from your original answer that you meant that since 力 contributes very little, you meant that its use is almost arbitrary in order to fill in the space because 能 is too short, but it seems I misunderstood.

@Pheonix I did say "力 contributes very little", but that's not because it's a meaningless character but because it's redundant. Stacking two similar kanji is a very common method of forming a compound. Please see my first reference for examples.

@naruto Makes sense, so they just used two kanji with similar meanings to produce a similar word (instead of using just one to avoid homophones)? And 力 means something like "the power to be able to do something" (ability) here? –

@Pheonix Yes, that's correct. 力 and 能 both work like a suffix meaning "-ability".

Like I mentioned in another answer to another of your questions, 能力 is a compound of two similarly meaning Chinese morphemes. These are extremely common, and may seem "redundant" to you. If you just rely on English translations of individual kanji, you won't figure out what some of the kanji contribute to the overall meanings. I don't know why the ancient Chinese felt the need to create these compounds, they just did. Other examples include 森林, 宗教, 法制, 法度, 制度, 過渡, 方向, 降臨, 行旅, 旅行, 希望, 反逆, 階級, 階段, 段階, 帰還, 疫病, 士卒, 狩猟, 摩擦, 告白, 平安, 平和, 和平, 海洋, 山岳, 神祇, 事情 (but not 情事), 事務, 言語. They're called 同義複詞 in Chinese linguistics. Here's a great list of more compounds.
As for, 能力, you've already done your homework on the individual kanji. The only thing I'd add is that it's classical Chinese compound, where it meant anything to the effect of "ability, capability, capacity, competency, etc.":

Records of the Grand Historian: 上幸盡其能力, 乃得至今
牛賦: 命有好醜，非若能力

If it exists in classical Chinese literature, you know what that means: Meiji translators must've used it to translate western concepts like "ability" or "faculty". Unlike 制度, the ancient meanings of 能力 happen to serendipitously match the modern meanings quite well.

Alright thanks! I was just confused how 力 (power / strength) to the meaning of ability, capacity. But as naruto said, power / strength seems to be used here to mean "the power / strength to do something" (i.e. ability).
